# redefining mean inside function

Tags: r, built-in

I would like to define a function `auto.na()` which redefines a whole set of univariate statistics to add "na.rm=TRUE" as the default.  for example,

```
mean.na <- mean ; mean <- function(...) mean.na(...,na.rm=TRUE)
```

I don't like this in itself, because this is too silent an important change.  hence, I would like to define a function in my .Rprofile that changes the meaning of many builtin functions:

```
auto.na <- function() {
   unistats <- c("mean", "sum", "sd", "median", "var", ...)
   for (u in unistats)
       paste0(u,'.na') <<- u ; u <<- function(..., na.rm=TRUE)
}
```

and then, I never again have to add "na.rm=TRUE".  good idea, bad execution.  this fails for the re-referencing, and versions like it fail with an error that I cannot change the value of a locked binding.  is this easy to do?

advice appreciated.  /iaw

PS: fortunately, some functions like summary and lm don't need to be added, because they are already na ignorers.  arguably, this facility is not entirely inconsistent.

Comment: this may be a case when using `assign` is what you're after, though I can't speak to how strongly I'd recommend doing this

Comment: `purrr::partial` sets some parameters, returning a modified version of a function, which can be handy. Setting any of this in .Rprofile is a bad idea, though, because your code will lose all portability.

Comment: Am I wrong saying you can do it by defining those functions in a new package (that would overload when loaded as having precedence in workspaces order)?

Comment: It's easy to do in a very wrong way: these functions are not all defined as `f(..., na.rm = FALSE)`, their formal arguments differ. For `mean` you'd actually want to overload `mean.default` so you don't break the dispatching on the generic function which has formal arguments `x` and `...`, not `...` and `na.rm`.

Comment: a package would indeed make a lot more sense (than an .Rprofile): `library(narmtrue)` .  ideally, each function would then allow `na.rm=FALSE` as a valid parameter, but this would invalidate the '...' in the way I defined it.  is this reinventing the wheel?  does something this obvious not already exist?